# Mehrune's Razor effect on Player in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

If an NPC is made to use [Mehrune's Razor](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Mehrunes'_Razor_(Skyrim)) on the player, does it have a chance to instantly kill the player?

Does magic resistance affect the chance? How does magic resistance interact with Mehrune's razor in general?

Comment: maybe its installs oblivion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't say with 100% certainty, since I haven't tested it, but based on information on the [Elder Scrolls Wiki's Mehrune's Razor page](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Mehrunes'_Razor_(Skyrim)#Footnotes), I can say that

**1) Will the razor effect work on the PC?** Probably.

The page mentions that two NPCs are immune to the effect, and that

> Game data shows both are part of the "Characters Immune to Mehrunes Razor" faction.

I assume that if the PC was part of this faction as well, they would have mentioned that, and that therefore it would work on the PC.

**2) Does magic resistance help?** Probably not.

The page mentions the formula used to calculate the effect:

> The DA07MehrunesRazorMagicEffectScript script reveals the enchantment grants a 1 percent chance to kill the target. However it uses the RandomInt() that generates a number between 0 and 100 and if the number is <=1 it kills the target, hence the % to kill is 1.98%.

There's nothing there about magic resistance. Since that would affect the percentage, which is stated as fact, I conclude that magic resistance has no effect.

Comment: The key here is that the enchantment grants the wielder of the Razor the 1.98% chance to kill its target. Effectively, this makes it function like an armor enchantment; magic resistance doesn't factor into one's own armor enchants, and it can indeed harm the PC if used by another character.